# Pycharm help using requests library

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, pycharm

Hey guys I really need help with this problem.
Whenever I try to print a url in its HTML form using the get() function, pycharm only prints it in one line instead of displaying the content of the web page in its HTML format

I've tried reinstalling the library but it keeps happening.

Comment: Hey, could you provide the code you're running and the URL you're trying to get the page from?

Comment: Sure, my code is the following:                                                                                           import bs4
import requests
import lxml

result = requests.get('https://www.crunchyroll.com/es')
print(result.text)

Comment: What if the content is in a single line? That's perfectly valid in HTML.

Comment: The way im require is in the displayed HTML form

Answer (score 0):

Without extra detail, I'd guess that you want to call `print(get(...).text)` instead of just `print(get(...))` because otherwise, it'll just print the reponse object which has other stuff in it like the HTTP response code.

Comment: Yes, thats what i am trying to do but it keeps printing in only one line the whole content